# Cronjob não reconhece o controller do CodeIginiter

Tags: php, codeigniter, cron

Estou tentando fazer com que um cronjob rode no CI, porem não estou conseguindo, aparece esse erro:

> **Fatal error**:  Class 'CI_Controller' not found in **/MeuCaminho/application/controllers/cron.php** on line **4**

**PHP**

```
<?php 
class Cron extends CI_Controller{ 
//put your code here 
public function index(){ 
    $arq = fopen("teste_cron.txt", "a+"); 
    fwrite($arq, "=======================TESTE CRONTAB======================================\n"); 
    fwrite($arq, "O CronTab executou este código na Data/Hora: ".date("d/m/Y H:i:s")."\n"); 
    fwrite($arq, "==========================================================================\n"); 
    fclose($arq); 
}}
```

**CAMINHO**

```
php -q /home/user/public_html/caminho_completo/application/controllers/cron.php
```

Alguém sabe me dizer como posso fazer?

Comment: Sugiro não usar um controller, mas sim um arquivo php simples.

Answer (score 0):

O erro parece estar na maneira como você chama o script pela linha de comando. [Segundo o manual](https://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/general/cli.html), você precisa navegar para a pasta do projeto e executar o `index.php`, passando para ele controller e action:

```
cd /home/user/public_html/caminho_completo/application/
/caminho-do-php/php index.php cron index
                               |     |
                               |   action
                          controller
```